# Justification of acceptance probability in simulated annealing

Tags: optimization, simulation, stochastic-processes, markov-process

In simulated annealing the acceptance probability for a new state in step $k$ is traditionally defined as
$$ P(\text{accept new})= \begin{cases}
\exp(-\frac{\Delta}{T_k}), & \text{ if } \Delta \geq 0 \\
1, & \text{ if } \Delta < 0 
\end{cases},$$
where $\Delta = f(\text{new}) - f(\text{old})$ is the change in objective function $f$ which is to be minimised and $T_k$ is a strictly decreasing positive sequence with $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} T_k=0.$

### Question

1. Is there a fundamental or conceptional justification for using specifically $\exp(-\frac{\Delta}{T_k})$ in the acceptance probability instead of any other term which fulfills the "obvious" requirements, i.e. being decreasing in $\Delta$ and converging to zero for $k\rightarrow\infty$ and $\Delta\rightarrow\infty$?
2. In which way is the analogy with statistical physics, where $f$ is energy and $T_k$ temperature, anything more than a superficial or "inspiring" analogy?

I would equally appreciate direct answers or references.

Comment: 1. Check `metropolis-hastings` 2. the analogy is purely nominal.